# strange compiler error when converting string literal (URL) into string

Tags: c#, url

```
string uURL = "http://www.httprecipes.com/” ;
```

causes compiler error "CS1010 Newline in constant"

Comment: Looks like there is two different kinds of quotes on that string.

Comment: There must be a unwanted character in the string that is not visible. Copy the `string uURL = "http://www.httprecipes.com/" ;` and paste it back into the code.

Comment: aha, well spotted! that's it... I was searching the keyboard just now asking myself where the hell is a second double-quote key, but then I realised I'dI copied the code out of a PDF...

Answer (score 0):

I think the strange closing double-quotation is causing the issue. Probably you copy-pasted the string from somewhere.

Please replace the character with correct double-quotation.

Answer (score 0):

`”` causes the issue, use `"` instead.

[image]